# I'mg getting an undefined variable in Ionic and I'm not sure why?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt a simple text in Ionic. Here's my code:

```
encryptedData : any;

encryptData(data){
  this.aes
      .encrypt(this.secureKey, this.secureIV, data)
      .then(res => {
        console.log("Encrypted Data: " + res);
        this.encryptedData = res;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("Error encrypting data: " + err);
      });
 }
```

the data is a simple plain text and it gets encrypted as I can see from the logs:

[image]

However the variable **encryptedData** comes as null after setting the (res) data to it. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you trying to read the value of `encryptedData `? It will have a value **only** after the promise is finished (so if you try to do it below the *catch* it won't work.

Comment: Yes I am trying to read this below the catch method, I noticed it only works inside the then block

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the world of "this" in JavaScript.

Arrow functions are bound to the execution context - in this example, it will be invoked with some kind of "this" that comes from Promise internals.

You can enforce calling context by using regular function combined with "bind(...)".

Please, take a look at the following example.

```
Promise
      .resolve("new value")
      .then((res) => {
        this.myProp = res;
      });
```

Will not work, but this:

```
Promise
    .resolve("new value")
    .then(function(res){
        this.myProp = res;
    }.bind(this));
```

will.

Take a look at this jsfiddle which reproduces your problem (open browser's devtools to see console output)
https://jsfiddle.net/mg7pjLz0/4/

Comment: Still not working, I am trying to read the variable below the Promise code block

Comment: Well, promises are executed asynchronously. Your are trying to access property before even then(...) code block was ran.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like encrypt() returns a Promise; in such a case, you are only able to use the return value inside the 'then' block. You should check, perhaps by doing console.log("Encrypted Data Assigned?: " + this.encryptedData); right after you  assignment if the value gets assigned. If the value is printed, then maybe you are trying to use the value before the async function returns.